# Search from an array of objects via array of string to get array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, javascript-objects

Hie All,

I have two arrays as below:

```
var arr1 = [ '1956888670', '2109171907', '298845084' ];
var arr2 = [ 
  { KEY: '1262875245', VALUE: 'Vijay Kumar Verma' },
  { KEY: '1956888670', VALUE: 'Sivakesava Nallam' },
  { KEY: '2109171907', VALUE: 'udm analyst' },
  { KEY: '298845084', VALUE: 'Mukesh Nagora' },
  { KEY: '2007285563', VALUE: 'Yang Liu' },
  { KEY: '1976156380', VALUE: 'Imtiaz Zafar' },
  ];
```

arr1 has keys and arr2 has key and value.
i want to output key and value of only those keys which are present in arr1.
Hence my output should be,

```
[{ KEY: '1956888670', VALUE: 'Sivakesava Nallam' },
  { KEY: '2109171907', VALUE: 'udm analyst' },
  { KEY: '298845084', VALUE: 'Mukesh Nagora' },]
```

Requesting your help to write a function to fetch required output using javascript.Thanks in advance.

Comment: eh... simple for loop?

Comment: it sounds like you want to loop through arr1 (should look at for loops and how to find the length of an array). The structure would be like for every value in arr1, (depending on arr1's value), get a value from arr2

Comment: There are countless similar questions. In search OP should thrust.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arr1 = [ '1956888670', '2109171907', '298845084' ];
var arr2 = [ 
  { KEY: '1262875245', VALUE: 'Vijay Kumar Verma' },
  { KEY: '1956888670', VALUE: 'Sivakesava Nallam' },
  { KEY: '2109171907', VALUE: 'udm analyst' },
  { KEY: '298845084', VALUE: 'Mukesh Nagora' },
  { KEY: '2007285563', VALUE: 'Yang Liu' },
  { KEY: '1976156380', VALUE: 'Imtiaz Zafar' },
  ];


  result = arr2.filter( function(obj) {
    return arr1.indexOf(obj.KEY) >= 0;
  });

  console.info(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `filter` - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var output = arr2.filter(function(item) {
  return arr1.indexOf(item.KEY) >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the filtering.

```js
var arr1 = ['1956888670', '2109171907', '298845084'],
    arr2 = [{ KEY: '1262875245', VALUE: 'Vijay Kumar Verma' }, { KEY: '1956888670', VALUE: 'Sivakesava Nallam' }, { KEY: '2109171907', VALUE: 'udm nalyst' }, { KEY: '298845084', VALUE: 'Mukesh Nagora' }, { KEY: '2007285563', ALUE: 'Yang Liu' }, { KEY: '1976156380', VALUE: 'Imtiaz Zafar' }],
    mySet = new Set,
    result;

arr1.forEach(function (a) {
    mySet.add(a);
});

result = arr2.filter(function (a) {
    return mySet.has(a.KEY);
});

console.log(result);
```